# How can we take the sum of each columns in SQL Server without using ;with cte?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can I take sum of each rows by two row sum in 3rd column?

Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

You can see for id 1 sum is 10 but for id 2 sum is 10+50 = 60
and third sum is 60+100 = 160 and so on.

With Cte it is working fine for me. I need with out `;with cte` means though code I need the sum

Example will as shown below

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ColumnA INT, ColumnB VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES (10,'1'), (50,'2'), (100,'3'), (5,'4'), (45,'5');

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT ColumnB, SUM(ColumnA) asum
   FROM @t 
   GROUP BY ColumnB
), cteRanked AS
(
   SELECT asum, ColumnB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) rownum
   FROM cte
) 
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(asum) 
     FROM cteRanked c2 
     WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum) AS ColumnA, 
    ColumnB
FROM
    cteRanked c1;
```

Comment: What is the problem with using CTE? In SQL Server 2012+ running total is calculated very efficiently using `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)`. In previous version you'll need a correlated subquery in some form.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov it is a long query it is a part of it so it take more time to execute the query, when more than 50000 of records ,

Comment: So, you think that using CTE makes your query slow, correct? CTE by itself doesn't affect the query performance in SQL Server. You can re-write the query as a bunch of nested SELECTs manually, but SQL Server does it already. It inlines CTE. If you are after a simple running total **and** you are using SQL Server 2012+, then there is a very efficient way to do it. In SQL Server 2008 a cursor may be more efficient than subqueries. Please clarify what version of SQL Server you use.

Comment: CTEs aren't a magical performance killer. Asking for a solution to not use a CTE in the belief that it will fix your performance issue is misguided.

Comment: because it is a lengthy query , it a part means 1/20 th of that query , if i use cte or temp table it will not affect to the rest of the query it will work only in that block thats y said not to use cte or temp table.

Answer (score 2):

One option, which doesn't require explicit analytic functions, would be to use a correlated subquery to calculate the running total:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Currency,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Currency) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS Sum
FROM yourTable t1
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: answer is write with cte; i need with out using with cte; sir ,

Comment: I only used a CTE in place of actual table.  Just replace the CTE with the actual table you are using.  As the comments mentioned, using a CTE won't affect things much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a simple running total.

There is an easy and efficient way to calculate running total in SQL Server 2012 and later. You can use `SUM(...) OVER (ODER BY ...)`, like in the example below:

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ColumnA INT, ColumnB VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES (10,'1'), (50,'2'), (100,'3'), (5,'4'), (45,'5');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    ColumnB
    ,ColumnA
    ,SUM(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnB 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumColumnA
FROM @t
ORDER BY ColumnB;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| ColumnB | ColumnA | SumColumnA |
+---------+---------+------------+
|       1 |      10 |         10 |
|       2 |      50 |         60 |
|       3 |     100 |        160 |
|       4 |       5 |        165 |
|       5 |      45 |        210 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

For SQL Server 2008 and below you need to use either correlated sub-queries as you do already or a simple cursor, which may be faster if the table is large.

Comment: how  this can  written in --->`(SUM(ISNULL(A.ColumnA,0) )AS decimal(18,3))`--->`SUM(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnB 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumColumnA` showing the following error `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`.

Comment: @DonaSusanIssac - if you're using `SUM() OVER (...)` then the query doesn't (necessairly) need a `GROUP BY` clause at all.

Comment: `SELECT
    EOMONTH (A.TransactDateTime) TransactDateTime, 
       CAST (SUM(ISNULL(A.Profit,0)) AS decimal(18,3)) Profit
    ,SUM(A.Profit) OVER (ORDER BY A.TransactDateTime  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumColumnA
FROM CostLedger A
    WHERE ISNULL(Profit,0)>0 AND YEAR(TransactDatetime)=YEAR(CAST ( '2017-May-01' as Date))
    
` by this it showing `Column 'CostLedger.TransactDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Sorry @DonaSusanIssac, it seems that you are trying to change the question significantly. My query in this answer returns the correct result based on the sample data in the question. If you have something more complicated than a simple running total, then it is better to ask another question and properly explain the problem. Provide a good relevant set of sample data that highlights the problem and explain what result you want to achieve.

Comment: ok no pblm  i think my code is same as your code simplicity only the error in this `Column 'CostLedger.TransactDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`